# Command to monitor file changes within a directory and execute command

Tags: command-line, bash, filesystem

I have a folder with a bunch of subfolders, these folders have `asciidoctor` formated filed with `.adoc` extension.

Every time I made changes to files (which is often) I need to run

```
asciidoctor -q filename.adoc
```

to compile it into HTML format.

I am trying to automate the process. so far I have come with this using [entr](http://entrproject.org/):

```
ls *.adoc | entr asciidoctor -q *.adoc
```

but only works with existing folder not for subfolders. I have tried this variation, but it doesn't work:

```
find . -name '*.adoc' | entr asciidoctor -q *.adoc
```

Any ideas how I could implement this automate process for all the subfolders?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you detect file changes](http://askubuntu.com/questions/513954/how-do-you-detect-file-changes)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Linux provides a nice interface for monitoring all file system events like creating, modifying, removing files. The interface is `inotify` family of system calls, the userspace utilities leveraging these calls are provided by the `inotify-tools` package in Ubuntu (available on the universe repository). If you don't have it already, install by:

```
sudo apt-get install inotify-tools
```

`inotify-tools` provides `inotifywait` and `inotifywatch` binaries, we need the first one.

---

So you want to run the command `asciidoctor -q some_file` when any `.adoc` file is modified (`some_file` will replaced by that), if so assuming your `.adoc` files are in directory `/foo/bar`, you can set the watch:

```
inotifywait -qm --event modify --format '%w' /foo/bar/*.adoc
```

- `-q` enables the quiet mode,  no info from `inotifywait` itself
- `-m` enables monitor mode, otherwise it will exit after the first event
- `--event modify`, we are only interested in `modify` event i.e. when a file is modified. Other possible values include `open`, `close` etc.
- `--format %w`, we only want the file name that is modified rather than bunch of other info as we will use the file name as input to another command
- `/foo/bar/*.adoc` will be expanded to all `.adoc` files under `/foo/bar` directory

---

Now the above will show you the filename whenever any is modified, now to run the command on the filename (assuming the command takes arguments via STDIN):

```
inotifywait -qm --event modify --format '%w' /foo/bar/*.adoc | while read -r file ; do
    asciidoctor -q "$file"
done
```

---

You can also setup a recursive watch on the directory, you will then need to use `grep` to filter the desired files only. Here setting the watch recursively (`-r`) on directory `/foo/bar` and using `grep` to filter only `.adoc` files:

```
inotifywait -qrm --event modify --format '%w%f' /foo/bar | grep '\.adoc$' | while read -r file ; do
    asciidoctor -q "$file"
done
```

When watching directories the output format specifier `%w` resolves to the directory name, so we need `%f` to get the file name. While watching files, `%f` would resolve to empty string.

Note that, you can also run `inotifywait` in daemon (`-d`) mode, you can also script the whole  thing, and/or run in background, and/or play with it more other options.

Also, you can replace `asciidoctor` with any other command of your choice, if you want.

Check `man inotifywait` to get more idea.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I also something similar for OSX. but I guess this is not the right place to ask.

Comment: @bran Yes, IMHO go to [UL](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), you can use this as a reference.

Comment: Great answer, just a minor correction. -q makes the program "less verbose", -qq (double q) makes it completely silent except for fatal errors.

Answer (score 11):

There are many tools out there, specially if you search through your repository

```
apt-cache search monitor | grep file
```

which gives us many tools. But you do not have to test them because I did that.

I have tested these tools and many others: `inotifywait` (from [`inotify-tools`](https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools/wiki)), [`fswatch`](https://emcrisostomo.github.io/fswatch/), `filewatch`, [`swatch`](https://swatch.sourceforge.net/),
[`fileschanged`](https://fileschanged.sourceforge.net/), and [`entr`](https://eradman.com/entrproject/).

Among these tools I found three of them useful and reliable:

- [`direvent`](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/direvent) | GNU written in C
- [`iwatch`](https://iwatch.sourceforge.net/index.html)   | in Perl
- [`fsniper`](https://github.com/l3ib/fsniper)

And from these three, the [`direvent`](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/direvent) is the best with no doubt.

## `direvent`

It is so useful and reliable to use that I have used it for a simple **pipeline** with my microservices I have.

`direvent.conf` file for watching

```
syslog {
    facility local0;
    tag "direvent";
    print-priority yes;
}

watcher {
    path /var/www/html/ir/jsfun/build/react recursive;
    file "*.js";
    event write;
    command "/usr/bin/xdotool search --onlyvisible  --class firefox key F5";
    option (stdout, stderr, wait);
}
```

This is just one of the config files I have in which whenever there is a change for **write** then this command is executed - which could be a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script as well.

No need to use `while` loop or other stuff.

---

### features

- recursively watching a directory
- can be run in **foreground** or **background** as a daemon
- portable. I have it in Ubuntu as well as CentOS7 server
- file name report
- regex to support file matching
- mulit-file watching (watch more then just one type of file)
- synchronize commands execution (if we have multi-watcher)
- syslog handling (log to syslog if we want)
- easy and good CLI and config file design to work with

Developed by [**Sergey Poznyakoff**](http://gray.gnu.org.ua/).

---

### Installing

```
sudo apt install direvent
```

But installing it using its source code is pretty easy and straightforward which gives you the last version (right now is: 5.1).

- [download](https://www.gnu.org.ua/software/direvent/download.html)
- [document](https://www.gnu.org.ua/software/direvent/manual/html_node/index.html)

Comment: It would be useful if each tool was a separate post, so that they could be voted on separately.

Comment: [`iwatch`](https://iwatch.sourceforge.net/index.html) hasn't been updated since 2009. I found it to be buggy [#2003873](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/iwatch/+bug/2003873)

Comment: `fileschanged` has been removed from Ubuntu repos.

Answer (score 8):

Using `inotifywait` is the typical approach, but there's also a separate utility called `inotify-hookable` that just lets you run a command when a file (or directory) changes:

```
inotify-hookable -f filename.adoc -c 'asciidoctor -q filename.adoc'
```

It seems to exit after triggering the command once; I don't see an option for continous watching, so you could do something like:

```
while true; do
    inotify-hookable -f filename.adoc -c 'asciidoctor -q filename.adoc'
    echo "== $(date) : executed, continuing to monitor..."
done
```

Note there are options to monitor several files or a directory, recursively, and options to ignore files/paths.

Comment: inotify-hookable does not exit after running the command for me. Hmm

Comment: inotify-hookable is installed from a different package: `sudo apt-get install inotify-hookable`

Answer (score -5):

Well I recommend the following.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script
for SRC in *.adoc; 
      do
      asciidoctor -q $SRC
  done
```

Comment: OP wants to run the command only when modifications are made..