# Strace run command on specific trace string match

Tags: 14.04, strace

I want to run a command on specific text match from trace output.
While strace is monitoring another running process.

I am using stransmit for streaming.
My requirement is to strace output from stransmit and execute a command if the trace matches a string.

Thanks

Comment: Related https://askubuntu.com/questions/819265/bash-script-to-monitor-file-change-and-execute-command

Comment: That is related to any change in file. I don't want to write logs to file, and do action on file change. Just want to execute command when the trace from running process is "a specific string"